# Put last two words in different span - PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, explode

I can't figure out the following: I have strings returned from which I want to put the first few words in some html tag and than the last two separately like this:

```
<p>This is a <span class="someclass">returned string</span></p>
```

I know I can explode the string into an array and make every word an iteration, but than I can only figure out how to put the first two words in a different html tag, and I want the last two. Each string can have a different number of words.

I was thinking of doing something with array count, like:

```
$string = this is a returned string;
$words = explode(" ", $string);
$count = count($words); // $words in this case is 5
$amountofwordsbeforespan = $count - 2;
echo '<p>'.$amountofwordsbeforespan.'<span class="somethingtostyleit">'.SOMETHING THAT PUTS THE LAST TWO HERE.'</span></p>';
```

But I think there should be an easier way.

Does someone know what is the cleanest way to accomplish this?

Comment: `array_pop` gets you the last element, so simply call that twice to get & remove the last two words from the splitted array - and `implode` the rest again to fill the first part …?

Comment: I'm 99.99% positive you do something funny here. Why would you assume it's always 2 last words that you want there?

Comment: @cbroe Thank you, im gonna look into that.

Comment: @roborobok I don't just assume that but it is designed that way. The last two words of specific parts of the design get some diffrent styling, so thats why I need them in a span. unfortunately I cannot predict how many words will be in each string

Comment: Just being curious, can you tell what that string is and what are these 2 last words?

Comment: @roborobok the string can be anything, depending on what the user is gonna fill in. That is why I'm searching for this and not just put it in hardcoded :)

Comment: @cbroe Thank you very much, I looked into it but it just removes the last iteration of the array. I will remember it cuz it can come in handy :D

Comment: Are you talking about `array_pop` now? Well guess why I said something about calling that _twice_ …

Comment: @cbroe yes I know, and for that part it works perfectly, but than I still need the last words, which the array_splice function comes in handy for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way using `array_splice()`,

```
<?php
$string = 'this is a returned string';
$words = explode(" ", $string ); 
$last_two_word = implode(' ',array_splice($words, -2 )); 
$except_last_two = implode(' ', $words);
$expected = '<p>'.$except_last_two.' <span class="someclass">'.$last_two_word.'</span></p>';
echo $expected;
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/d3DYq

Comment: @Maartje glad it helps you somehow :)